# 2 instances of postgresql but I really need one

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I happen to have 2 installed instances of postgresql at my machine: 9.1 and 9.2:

```
sudo service postgresql status
9.1/main (port 5432): down
9.2/main (port 5433): down
```

They are located at `/etc/postgresql/9.1/` and `/etc/postgresql/9.2/`. Then I run `9.2` by saying `sudo service postgresql start` But this command fails:

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I really want to use `9.2` only, I don't need 2 instances.

Do you have any idea of how to either remove `9.1` safely or make `9.2` to be the main, default instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the 9.1 instance (assuming you don't want to keep the data):

```
sudo pg_dropcluster 9.1 main

dpkg --get-selections | grep postgres
sudo apt-get purge postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client-9.1
```

That might do it, but the occasional tool might complain that it prefers to have the 9.2 instance run on port 5432.  So with the 9.2 instance shut down, edit the configuration file `/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf` and change the `port =` setting.  Then restart it.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the package `postgresql`, you will always get the newest version and keep the old one.
You can install `postgresql-9.2` to ignore newer versions and migrate when you really want to.